# How can I access and update a token directly in TokenFilter class in apache lucene?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, lucene

I'm writing a plugin for elasticsearch that would perform natural language analysis based on integration with an existing analyser (I suppose the details are irrelevant for now).

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding or finding information about how lucene is supposed to work. I have seen that there are these Attributes like CharTermAttribute that are somehow stored in a map of Class -> Attribute. I don't understand how is this supposed to be working. How can I directly access a current token?

And how do I update it? Which Attributes should be updated?

I need to be pass strings to that analyser I'm integrating so that I can get some kind of output.

Can someone at the very least point me in the right direction?

(To be precise I'm writing a subclass of TokenFilter class)

Comment: what did you try so far? i would recommend to take a look at any token filter class that Lucene have (for example synonym)

Comment: I examined StandardFilter, Snowball, MorfologikFilter, Stempel and a few others and I've dug through the code.
I'm the kind of person that gets stuck without seeing the bigger picture, right now its just the way it is coded is extremely confusing to me. Why did they choose to do it this way? Was there no way to make it simpler? What are the design decisions in creating lucene?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a subclass of `TokenFilter` you need to take a look at it:

First idea of the architecture of `TokenFilter` - this is an abstract class; subclasses must override `incrementToken()`. Also, there are several methods in it - `end()`, `close()`, `reset()`. It's very important to call super methods if you're overriding it.

However, most of the stuff is happening in `incrementToken()`. Overall architecture is the following, that in your `incrementToken` you need to call input `TokenStream` that is coming to you - to get next token (let's imagine your parent `TokenStream` is `WhitespaceTokenizer`) and later to updated token attributes so they would be accessible later.

There are about 10 token attributes that already exist and most likely you just need to use them. Let me name a few of the important ones: `CharTermAttribute` (contains token text), `PositionIncrementAttribute` (set the distance from the prior term, defaulted to 1), `PositionLengthAttribute` (most of the analyzers ignore it, but it could be useful in the NLP processing to actually have TokenStreams as graphs), and some others. Full list could be as usual found in the [source code of Lucene](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes).

Usually, after you invoke `incrementToken()` you're getting token text from the previous `TokenStream` and do some manipulation with it.

I could imagine that some code related to NLP analysis could look like this:

```
if (!input.incrementToken()) {
    return false; // no more tokens left
} else {
    final CharTermAttribute attribute = input.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class); //getting token text from the previous TokenStream
    final String result = doNLP(attribute.toString()); // invoking your NLP analysis on token text
    termAtt.copyBuffer(result , 0, suffix.length()); // storing output result of your NLP analysis in the CharTermAttribute  that you have in your TokenStream, so later indexing pipeline could use it
}
```

Of course, you would need to initialize this `termAtt` in your class with something like this: `CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);`